# Cannot access "world readable" preferences in Honeycomb

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a free game and I'm making a paid version. The free game stores an integer high score in a shared preference file I created in MODE_WORLD_READABLE mode. The paid version needs to copy this score over if the free version is installed.

The code I'm using for this is as follows:

```
Context c = paidContext.createPackageContext("my.app.packagename", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences prefs = c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

The first line creates the context for the free app if it exists (you get an exception otherwise). The second line gets the shared preferences file. I can then use prefs.getInt to get the high score.

The problem: This works just fine in Android 1.5, 2.1, 2.3 etc. but it isn't working for me in the Android 3.0 or 3.1 emulator. The code above runs but getInt always returns the default value.

Is this a bug? A feature of Honeycomb? Are there some app permissions I don't know about? How can I diagnose this further?

Comment: It may be better to sign both apps with the same set of certificates and set them to both use the same `android:sharedUserId` in their manifests. That way, they'll be able to share data in private.

Answer (score 1):

Although helpful, Roman's comment on the question does not provide an answer. To expand upon it, Android does not guarantee that preferences will be accessible across processes; In fact, the documentation (at the top of [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)) explicitly states that inter-process access is not supported (even though it works, sometimes). By signing the applications with different certificates, you're ensuring the applications cannot run in the same process, which is Android's method of sandboxing.

For what it's worth, I originally attempted to use SharedPreferences with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` as a means for making data accessible between two differently-signed applications. I ultimately ran into issues due to some cases where the inter-process reading wouldn't work (it seemed to be an order-of-operations thing). Instead, I implemented what I should have done in the first place which was inter-process communication (IPC) using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) + [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) implementation.